# No muestra INF en php

Tags: php

no se por que no me muestra INF, cuando divido cualquier numero entre 0

Calculadora.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora Simple</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculadora Simple</h1>
        <!– creamos el selector de operaciones ->
        Seleccione el operador a operar:
        <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
            <select name="operador">
                <option value="sumar">Suma</option>
                <option value="restar">Resta</option>
                <option value="multiplicar">Multiplicación</option>
                <option value="divir">División</option>
            </select><br/>

            <!–  Introducimos primer numero ->
            Introduce el primer número
            <input type="text" name="valor1"><br />
            <!–  Introducimos segundor numero ->
            Introduce el Segundo número
            <input type="text" name="valor2"><br />
            <!–  Borrar los valores ->
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
            <!–  Recoger los datos ->
            <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**resultado.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting (0);

    if(($_POST["valor1"] !="") && ($_POST["valor2"] !="")){
        if($_POST["operador"] =="sumar"){
            $opeperadorSimbolo="+";         
            $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] + $_POST["valor2"];
        }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "restar") {
            $opeperadorSimbolo="-";         
            $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] - $_POST["valor2"];
        }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "multiplicar") {
            $opeperadorSimbolo="*";  
            $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] * $_POST["valor2"];
        }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "dividir") {
            $opeperadorSimbolo="/";  
            $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"];
        }

        echo 'El resultado de: '.$_POST["valor1"].' '.$opeperadorSimbolo .' '.$_POST["valor2"].' es: '.$resultado ;                     
        print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a> ');
    }else {
        print ("Introduzca un numero valido");
        print ('<br /><a href="calculadora.php">Volver</a>') ;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinito es un concepto matematico no un número, en el caso de `n/0 = x` el resultado no es infinito, es una indefinición o un error lógico.

En php [INF](https://www.php.net/manual/es/math.constants.php) es una constante que es tratada como un float y puede ser positivo o negativo, pero no puede ser el resultado de una indefinición. Una división por cero en PHP es una operación que se intentará calcular teoricamente por siempre,entrando en un bucle infinito, para prevenir esto PHP lanzará la excepción [`DivisionByZeroError`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php).

No obstante si es necesario puedes controlar con un condicional si el divisor es igual a cero y como proceder en dicho caso, asignando INF por ejemplo:

```
if (/*operaciones anteriores*/){}
elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "dividir") {
    $opeperadorSimbolo="/"; 

    if( $_POST["valor2"] != 0 ) { 
        $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"];
    } else {
        // realizamos lo que creamos oportuno si el divisor es cero
        $resultado = INF;
    }
}
```

Comment: }elseif ($_POST["operador"] == "dividir") {
         
         $opeperadorSimbolo="/"; 
         echo ("hola");
         if( $_POST["valor2"] != 0 ) { 
          $resultado = $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"];
         } else {
          // realizamos lo que creamos oportuno si el divisor es cero
          $resultado = INF;
         }
        }

Comment: copio este código y no me sale ni el simbolo ni echo, copio la salida " El resultado de: 1 5 es: " cuando divido

Comment: no se mete en el == dividir

Comment: @kit La parte del `dividir` es la misma que tenias en tu código, simplemente se modificó el interior. En tu formulario tienes `value="divir"` en lugar de `value="dividir"`, corrigelo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para entender lo que ocurre en el caso de la división por cero en PHP hay que revisar [el código fuente](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/db0079023421b8048f090ee04adb992e09132553/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1223):

```
        if (Z_LVAL_P(op2) == 0) {
            zend_error(E_WARNING, "Division by zero");
            ZVAL_DOUBLE(result, ((double) Z_LVAL_P(op1) / (double) Z_LVAL_P(op2)));
            return SUCCESS;
```

En lenguaje llano: Cuando el divisor (`op2`)  es igual a `0`:

- Lanza un `zend_error` del tipo `E_WARNING` con el texto `*Division by zero*`
- Convierte a `double` el dividendo (`op1`)  y el divisor (`op2`), los divide y asigna a `result` el resultado de esa división
- Retorna `SUCCESS`

Si haces una prueba cualquiera verás en efecto que el resultado que se almacena en una divisón por cero es un booleano false.

```
$result=1/0;
var_dump($result);
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(false)
```

Si emulamos lo que indica el código fuente, verás el mismo resultado:

```
$result=(double) 1 / (double) 0;
var_dump($result);
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(false)
```

---

#### ¿Por qué no veo false en pantalla?

Porque `false` no es un valor imprimible. Si haces algo como `echo false;` no verás nada en pantalla.

---

#### ¿Qué hago?

Pues ser coherente. La división por cero se controla muy fácil. En tu código:

```
$resultado = ($_POST["valor2"]!=0) ? $_POST["valor1"] / $_POST["valor2"] : 0;
```

Aquí `$resultado` será `0` si el divisor es `0` y se evita el Wargning, porque nunca se lanzará una división por cero.

Comment: copio este código y lo mismo que el compañero, "El resultado de: 1 5 es: "

Comment: no se mete en el == dividir